# Join 3 tables using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How can I build a model using Entity Framework to join 3 tables?

At the moment I have:

```
public class KeywordAdCategory
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Keyword_Id", Order = 0)]
    public int Keyword_Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Ad_Id", Order = 1)]
    public int Ad_Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Category_Id", Order = 2)]
    public int Category_Id { get; set; }
}
```

But I don't have any navigation properties.

Is there a better way to build a relashionship between 3 tables using Entity Framework?

Also the Keyword, Ad and Category models:

```
public class Keyword
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Ad
{
    // Primary properties
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public AdOperation AdOperation { get; set; }
    public Member Member { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }

    private ICollection<Feature> _features;
    public virtual ICollection<Feature> Features
    {
        get { return _features ?? (_features = new HashSet<Feature>()); }
        set { _features = value; }
    }
}

public class Category
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryParent_Id { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryGroup_Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public Keyword Keyword { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using Code-First Entity Framework here, and that you have your `KeywordAdCategory` object in your database as well. In which case, just simply do the following in your `KeywordAdCategory` class to do the proper mapping:

```
[Key, ForeignKey("Keyword")]
[Column("Keyword_Id", Order = 0)]
public int Keyword_Id { get; set; }

[Key, ForeignKey("Ad")]
[Column("Ad_Id", Order = 1)]
public int Ad_Id { get; set; }

[Key, ForeignKey("Category")]
[Column("Category_Id", Order = 2)]
public int Category_Id { get; set; }

public virtual Keyword Keyword { get; set; }

public virtual Ad Ad { get; set; }

public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

Doing this should do the proper mappings, put FKs on your `KeywordAdCategory` table, and thus give you the ability to have good navigation properties to the other objects.

Comment: Hi, thanks! You use the ForeignKey property to build a relashionship between the key and the Navigation Property? Regards

Comment: Yep. That's the beautiful thing with Entity Framework. You include one simple annotation like that and it will automatically populate the navigation properties when you call for that object.